# How to use std::map in Windows kernel? STLPort?

Tags: c++, windows, stl, cross-platform, kernel

In my recent project, a data structure like `std::map` is strongly demanded. However, the default implementations of `std::map` use C++ exceptions, which is not allowed in Windows kernel.

I think it is hard to reinvent `std::map` in a short time without any bug or performance penalty. So, I want to know whether there exists a substitution of `std::map` in Windows kernel.

STLPort may be a candidate. But I don't know how to extract its `std::map` only and disable C++ exceptions.

Comment: [Judy](http://judy.sourceforge.net/) and [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) are the first two things that come to mind.  Writing one yourself with `vector` iterator invalidation rules should be pretty straightforward and easy.

Comment: what in `map` throws? All I can see is if your allocator or compare objects throw it would throw (and you can provide those yourself), but otherwise nothing throws, does it?

Comment: @Dave, The compiler will generate exception-handler code, which is not compatible with Windows kernel that has its own exception mechanism. It has nothing to do with whether throwing an exception at run-time.

Comment: Try compiling with exceptions disabled, and do not use `map::at`?  You might also have to replace the allocator with one that doesn't throw exceptions, if your default allocator throws exceptions (I don't know if it will).  And yes, writing an associative container using `std::vector` is easy: if your `map` use is "populate map, use map" and not "add, remove, use, add, remove, use, wash, repeat", a `std::vector` based associative container is much faster than a `map` and uses less memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ code in kernel mode has several (severe) limitations that precede the issues of not having (full) standard libraries.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487420.aspx

> Although it is not currently possible to provide a strict and testable definition of the “completely safe” subset of C++ for use in kernel-mode code, some useful guidelines are available for constructs that are usually safe and those that are usually not.

And

> ### C++ Issues for Kernel-Mode Drivers
>
> Microsoft developers have discovered a number of areas where C++ presents particular problems for kernel-mode drivers.
>
> #### Code in Memory
>
> The most severe problem with using C++ for writing kernel-mode drivers is the
>   management of memory pages, particularly code in memory, rather than data. It
>   is important that large drivers be pageable, and paged code is not always in
>   memory. All of the code that will be needed must be resident before the
>   system enters a state in which paging cannot occur.
>
> The way the C++ compiler generates code for non-POD classes and templates
>   makes it particularly difficult to know where all the code required to
>   execute a function might go and thus difficult to make the code safely
>   pageable. The compiler automatically generates code for at least the
>   following objects. These objects are put “out of line,” and the developer has
>   no direct control over the section in which they are inserted, which means
>   they could happen to be paged out when needed.
>
> - Compiler-generated code such as constructors, destructors, casts, and
>     assignment operators. (These can often be explicitly provided, but it
>     requires taking care to recognize that they need to be provided.)
> - Adjustor thunks, used to convert between various classes in a hierarchy.
> - Virtual function thunks, used to implement calls to virtual function.
> - Virtual function table thunks, used to manage base classes and polymorphism.
> - Template code bodies, which are emitted at first use unless explicitly instantiated.
> - The virtual function tables themselves.
>
> The C++ compiler does not provide mechanisms for direct control of where
>   these entities are placed in memory. The pragmas necessary to control memory
>   placement were not designed with C++ in mind.
>
> #### Libraries
>
> There are a number of distinct concerns in creating and using libraries:
>
> - The name of exported C++ functions can vary from one release to another.
> - Not all of the functions available in user mode are available in the kernel-mode libraries.
> - The Standard Template Library is designed to work with data objects from a single DLL.

Comment: By default, a driver's code is always resident in non-paged memory; except for those explicitly declare that some codes are pageable, i.e. #pragma alloc_text(PAGE, ...).

Comment: @xmllmx "by default" being the important part. But if you know your function is only going to run below `DISPATCH_LEVEL` you really wanna mark it as `PAGED_CODE()` and with said `#pragma`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look around you should probably find an alternative to std::map. 
Why do you need std::map, is it a hash-table you need? Then you could probably use [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.com/uthash/) which is a c imlemented hashtable.